# How can GSON be configured to recognize ISO date fields as parse them as Date objects?

Tags: java, json, gson

This code:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("now", new Date());

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
        .create();
String json = gson.toJson(map);
System.out.println(json);
```

produces something like `{"now":"2023-03-11T12:34:56.789Z"}`

Contrarily, undoing the action like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType());
```

fails to produce the input data - instead giving output like `{"now":"2023-03-11T12:34:56.789Z"}`.

The date string stays a string instead of being converted back to a `Date` object.

How may the string be parsed back into a `Map` so that GSON **recognises** the date string and parses it back to a `Date` object.

The regex pattern `"\\d{1,4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}\\:\\d{2}\\:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}Z"` roughly correlates to the date pattern.

Basically, I need to tell GSON by configuration:
If the string matches regex part (DATE_PATTERN) deserialize it as a date.

*Note: I am aware that deserializing to a class with date field would work properly since the field type gives GSON a hint. I need GSON to determine the target type simply based on the format of the string.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible; Gson [does not allow](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/1da826dc6c8eb85ad9ed97e120823428fe1236f4/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/Gson.java#L283-L285) overwriting the default type adapter factory for `Object`.

There are probably the following alternatives:

- Manually process the `Map` after it was deserilized with Gson and convert the values
- Have a model class with `Object` as field type (if directly specifying `Date` is not possible for some reason), and then place a [`@JsonAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) annotation on the field specifying your custom adapter factory
- Specify one of the general purpose interfaces implemented by `Date` (`Serializable`, `Cloneable` or `Comparable`) as value type of the map, e.g. `Map<String, Serializable>`, and then register a type adapter factory for that interface.
  This is possibly not a very clean solution and of course only works if the other deserialized values of the map implement that interface as well.
- Register a custom type adapter factory for `Map` which performs conversion of the values